# Win32 C When closing window it crashes werfault.exe appears in taskmanager

Tags: c, winapi, crash

I think it has to do with DispatchMessage and the Window Procedure probably wrong though been spending a long time on this I rather ask for help now I might have done something wrong looked everywhere to find out the cause of this I might just be stupid and not realizing what the problem is itself I created a structure to hold everything for my window I am trying to make a wrapper CreateWindowApplication is there so I can create a window everything works except when I close it.

```
// Header
typedef struct WindowApplication WindowApplication;

struct WindowApplication
{
 HINSTANCE hInstance;
 HWND hwnd;
 const wchar_t* title;
 int width;
 int height;
 UINT flags;
 int shouldClose;

 WindowApplication* next;
 WindowApplication* prev;
 WindowApplication* windowdata;
};


// WindowApplication.c
WindowApplication* CreateWindowApplication(const wchar_t* title, int width, int height, UINT flags)
{
 WindowApplication* window;
 window = (WindowApplication*)calloc(1, sizeof(WindowApplication));

 window->title = title;
 window->width = width;
 window->height = height;
 window->flags = flags;

 window->next = window->windowdata;
 window->windowdata = window;

 WindowApplicationWin32(window);

 return window;
};


// WindowApplicationWin32.c
void WindowApplicationWin32(WindowApplication* window)
{
WNDCLASSEXW wc = {};
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.hInstance = window->hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = window->title;
wc.lpszMenuName = window->title;
wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImageW(window->hInstance, L"icon.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 512, 512, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImageW(window->hInstance, L"icon.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(window->hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = 0;

RegisterClassExW(&wc);

window->hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0,
                               window->title,
                               window->title,
                               WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                               CW_USEDEFAULT,
                               CW_USEDEFAULT,
                               window->width,
                               window->height,
                               0,
                               0,
                               0,
                               0);

ShowWindow(window->hwnd, SW_SHOW);
};

int WindowApplicationWin32Events(WindowApplication* window)
{
MSG msg = {};
while(PeekMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessageW(&msg);
}
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uMsg)
{
 case WM_DESTROY:
  PostQuitMessage(0);
  break;
 default:
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
 }
 return 0;
};
// main.c
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
WindowApplication* window = WindowApplicationWindow(L"Demo", 640, 480, 0);

while(!WindowApplicationShouldClose(window))
{
   WindowEvents(window);
};
return 0;
};
```

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve]. There is no include stack, no prototypes, and no `WinMain`

Comment: `window->next = window->windowdata;` copies from a member that isn't set until the next line (unless it is meant to be `NULL` from the `calloc` behaviour).

Comment: There the full example and I don't think window-> window->data is the issue.

Comment: Just saying there seems to be some slackness. `window->prev` doesn't get set, except as the `calloc` behaviour, and the recent edit calls an entirely different function.

Comment: You say "everything works" but it does not compile. Basic syntax errors, missing functions and so on.

Comment: I use the GCC compiler

Comment: If you say there is missing functions I didn't add everything from the header do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of changes I kinda got it running. I think the issue is that after `PostQuitMessage(0);` function `WindowApplicationWin32Events` does not return anything and even if it returns it should be returning final message in the function `WinMain`. This is not happening, so instead execution just goes back to `WindowApplicationWin32Events` and gets stuck there.

Solution could be to do `return (int) msg.wParam;` at the end of `WindowApplicationWin32Events` and then in `WinMain` `WindowApplicationWin32Events` result should be final return instead of `return 0;`

You can check it out here: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html

**EDIT:**

Another thing is that "Unlike GetMessage, the PeekMessage function does not wait for a message to be posted before returning." So it exits loop quickly after no messages and then keeps coming back to `WindowApplicationWin32Events` like crazy and can be triggering error reporting (werfault.exe).

Get vs Peek: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage

Comment: Does it show a werfault in taskmanager after closing thanks for the help too.

Comment: no, then it closes normally and don't see werfault after closing. Also it could be something else in your case. For example using `PeekMessageW` got my cpu stuck on 100%, but i didn't check what was that. End up using `GetMessage`.

Comment: Interesting, Nice to know when I used PeekMessageW it ended showing werfault after words didn't know what was causing it.

Comment: I checked a bit about  `PeekMessage` and edited  answer.